# The MGF of X is bounded by the MGF of X'. Is the same true for the expectation of any convex function?

Tags: probability-theory, convex-analysis

Consider two scalar random variables $X$ and $X'$ such that $E[X]=E[X']$, and assume that the moment-generating function of $X$ is dominated by that of $X'$, meaning that for all $t\in \mathcal R$,
$$ E[e^{tX}] \leq E[e^{tX'}]. $$
Let $f$ be any convex function.

**Conjecture**: $ E[f(X)] \leq E[f(X')]. $

**Attempts:**
If the statement is true, it seems that it should follow relatively straight-forwardly by using Jensen's inequality and the assumptions in some way. However, applying Jensen to $f$ itself just gives the same upper bound of $f(E[X])=f(E[X'])$ for both sides. I have tried to insert the exponential and logarithm somewhere, in an attempt to use the MGF bound and Jensen's, starting with things like
$ \log E [\exp (f(x))]$.
However, I have not been able to progress from this.
Perhaps one can use the fact that the MGF bound holds for all $t$.

**Question:** Is the conjecture true? If not, is there a counter-example? Can it be made true by introducing additional assumptions, such as saying that $f$ is increasing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably not in general, but the question is very interesting.

Let's say we have a function $f(s)$ such that

$$f(s) = \int_I e^{s t} \rho(t) d t$$

(similar to a Laplace transform).

Then we can write

$$E(f(X)) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(s)  p_X(s) d s= \int_{\mathbb{R}} \int_I e^{s t} \rho(t) p_X(s) d t ds$$

Now change the order of the integration and get

$$E(f(X)) = \int_I E(e^{t X}) \rho(t) dt$$

that is, $E(f(X))$ is the average of the $E(e^{tX})$ ( "since" $f(s)$ is the average of $e^{st}$).

Now we see that we do get some result if we can write $f$ as a weighted sum ( integral) with  $\rho(t)\ge 0$ (  positivity is important).

Now, you do have classes of functions that are positive averages of exponentials. For instance, [totally monotone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernstein%27s_theorem_on_monotone_functions) functions.

A very interesting question. Perhaps the converse is true in some sense ( if the inequality always holds, then $f$ is a positive mixture of exponentials).  This looks very much like [Farkas's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Farkas%27_lemma).

$\bf{Added:}$

I have found a counterexample based on the following:

Let $p_1$, $p_2$ be the PDF of the two distributions $X_1$, $X_2$. What we know is that

$$\int_{\mathbb{R}} e^{t x} p_1(x) d x\le \int_{\mathbb{R}} e^{t x} p_2(x)dx$$

for all $t \in \mathbb{R}$. Does that imply

$$\int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x) p_1(x) d x \le f(x) p_2(x) d x$$

for all convex functions?  It certainly does for all positive linear combinations (and limit of them) of functions $x \mapsto e^{t x}$, but not for all convex ones.  Indeed, positive linear combinations of $x \mapsto e^{t x}$ have all derivatives of even order $\ge 0$. Now, let us consider a convex function $f(x)$ on $[-1, 1]$ with  $f^{4}(0) < 0$.  For instance, start with the positive function $g(x) = 2-x^2$ and integrate twice. So take $f(x) = 1 + x^2 - \frac{x^4}{12}$.  Now, try to exploit the fact that the $4$-th derivative at $0$ is $<0$ as some sort of integral  being negative. Consider the expression

$$\frac{f(x-2 h) - 4 f(x-h) + 6 f(x) - 4 f(x+h) + f(x+2 h)}{h^4}$$

This is the discrete version of $f^{(4)}(x)$ and it turns out to be constant $-2< 0$.

However, for an exponential function $e^{t x}$ the expression is $\ge 0$.

Now, we construct our example as follows:

Consider the discrete random variables: $X'$ with a discrete distribution $p_{X'}(-2) = p_{X'}(2) = \frac{1}{8}$, $p_{X'}(0) = \frac{6}{8}$, and $X$ with $p_{X}(-1) = p_{X}(1) = \frac{4}{8}$.

One checks directly that we have a counterexample.

Note: it would be interesting to find out what is the (closed) positive linear span of exponential functions?  Does is contain all (smooth) functions with derivatives of even order positive?  Seems like an interesting question.

$\bf{Added:}$ The closed positive linear span of functions $x \mapsto e^{a x}$ is invariant under multiplication ( by $e^{ax}$).  So all those functions $f$ satisfy

$$(e^{a x} f(x))^{(2n)} e^{-a x} \ge 0$$

for all $n \ge 0$ natural, and all $a \in \mathbb{R}$.

( so  there are more conditions than $f^{(2n)} >0$)  In this way we can get a counterexample to the problem with the function $f(x) = \cosh x -1/2$ ( in a similar way, using discrete second derivatives, and a convenient $a$).

One wonders now if we have enough conditions to determine the closed positive linear span of the exponentials.

$\bf{Added:}$ In fact, since we also need $E[X]= E[X']$, we can obtain $E[f(X)] \le E[f(X')]$ for all functions $f$ that are positive linear combinations of $e^{t x}$ $+$ some constant ( so $\cosh x-1/2$ is no counterexample).  However, here is another counterexample of $f(x)$ for the same $X$, $X'$  convex on full $\mathbb{R}$ ( the previous one had to be linearly extendend outside $[-2,2]$)

$$f(x) = 1+x^2 -\frac{1}{4} x^4 + \frac{1}{25} x^6$$

In general, if $f$ has some derivative of even order $f^{(2n)}$  ($n> 0$) not positive everywhere, we can similarly get a counterexample with some $X$, $X'$.

I am not sure how to characterize the functions $f$ that are positive linear combinations of exponential $+$ some constant. Clearly they satisfy : all derivatives $f^{(2n)}\ge 0$  (  for $n> 0$).

Note:

Here is a function $f(x)$ for which the inequality  Does hold:

$$f(x) = \frac{e^x-1}{x}$$

Indeed, we have $f(x) = \int_0^1 e^{t x} d t$.

Since it is a combination of $e^{t x}$ with $t\ge 0$, all of its derivatives are $\ge 0$.

Comment: Thank you for the insight. So if we apply the MGF assumption, we can establish the result for any totally monotone function, correct?
I think I would not mind restricting the domain of $X$ and $X'$ to $[0,\infty)$, and further assume that $f$ is convex, lower semi-continuous, and monotonically increasing. But this does not necessarily imply absolute monotonicity, correct?

Comment: @Finley Marsh:  You are welcome. The moral is : if $E(f_i(X)]\le E(f_i(X'))$ then it is true for any $f$ positive combination of the $f_i$'s. Now your $f_i$'s are some exponentials. Now you can see what combinations of those functions we can get.  The combinations of $e^{-s t}$  ( for $s \ge 0$), as functions of $t \in [0, \infty)$ are well understood, under the link there are characterizations of them. For instance, ever $1/t^a$, with $a\in (0,1)$ is such a combination ( integral in fact)

Comment: A fn on $[0, \infty)$  is absolute monotone if and only its derivatives have constant signs that alternate : $+, - + , - \ldots$ ( the theorem of Bernstein).  (It does follow from an older theorem of Hausdorff for moments of measures on $[0,1]$ , and all can be proved on perhaps 2 pages). So only positive, monotone, convex is not enough, you also need $f^(3)< 0$, $f^(4) > 0$ etc ( necessity is easy since it is true for a fn like  $e^{-a t}$

Comment: Thanks for the update. One thing that slightly confused me is that, while $f(x)=1+x^2-x^4/12$ is certainly convex on $[-\sqrt 2, \sqrt 2]$, it is not convex in a larger interval, and your example includes $\{-2,+2\}$ in the support. Is the idea that $f(x)$ is convex on the set $\{-2,-1,0,1,2\}$? With $\cosh(x)$, I did not quite understand how this would lead to a counterexample. I appreciate the point that the relevant question seems to be the closed positive linear span of the exponentials --- this does indeed seem like it would fully characterize the class of functions we can consider.

Comment: Added: If $X$ is bounded to $[0,1]$ and $X’$ is Bernoulli, a similar result is shown in Lemma 3 here: https://arxiv.org/pdf/cs/0411099.pdf. However, the technique used there relies on boundedness. Perhaps one needs to assume that the support of $X$ is contained in the convex hull of the support of $X’$?

Comment: Right,$f(x)$  is only convex on an interval containing all of the values of $X$, $X'$. If could be extendend to a convex function on $R$, by taking the linear approsximations at $2$ and at $-2$.  I will write the explicit example for $\cosh x -1/2$, but the idea is the same: find a lineer differential expression that is positive on all  exponential, but not on your function.

Comment: @FinleyMarsh: Was wrong with $\cosh x -1/2$, since we also need $E[X] = E[X']$ -- that means we are allowed to add constants to positive linear combinations of exponentials.  Here is another strictly convex function that works ( same counterxample for $X$, $X'$) $f(x) = 1 + x^2 -\frac{1}{4} x^4 + \frac{1}{25} x^6$  -- wobbly but still convex

Comment: @FinleyMarsh: I looked at the paper you indicated, it's Lemma 3.  Yes, it works for exponentials right away because of independence, if we prove for $n=1$ ( for exponentials) Even for $n=1$ for a general convex function, the lemma is interesting( dimension $1$) it is interesting, you would think that Jensen goes the other way, but you need to draw a picture.  Probably the $n=2$ case should be illuminating.

Comment: I cannot thank you enough for your help. I marked your answer as a solution, it is very clear that more conditions on $f$ are needed. Bernstein's theorem and related results seem like a good direction -- I imagine something similar should hold for functions where all derivatives are positive, for instance. Perhaps all 4th derivatives being positive is enough.

Comment: (All even* derivatives). The most simple example perhaps: I'm curious if it holds for $f(x)=x^2$, or more generally for all polynomials with positive coefficients. It is not clear to me whether they can be written as mixtures of exponentials. Can we differentiate the MGF bound wrt $t$ and get something nice? It doesn't imply that all moments of $X$ are bounded by moments of $X'$, does it?

Comment: @FinleyMarsh: Oh, no worries.  Lemma 3 in Maurer's paper, uses some basic inequalities for convex functions.  Now,  whether something is a mixture of certain exponentials is not clear. There are some necessary conditions.  I think $x^2+1$ does not pass.  I'll get back to you with more details.

Comment: @FinleyMarsh: Here is a necessary condition for $f(x)$ to be a mixture of exponentials: for every  $x$ the sequence $(f^{(n)}(x))_n$ is a sequence of moments (see Hamburger problem) ( not hard to check directly). But that imposes a bunch of conditions that you can check won't work for some of the examples given.  It is interesting if those conditions are sufficient.